# git, apache, smart-http, ubuntu, convert from SSH access, does not ask for user, password

Tags: git, apache, passwords, authorization, smart-http

In the process of converting a ubuntu private git repo from ssh access to smart http via apache.

Currently client .git/config contains:

```
url = https://some-domain/git/my-project.git
```

When assessed via:

```
git remote -v show origin
```

The server reports:

```
.../apache2/error.log
AH00027: No authentication done but request not allowed without authentication for /git/my-project.git/info/refs. Authentication not configured?
.../apache2/access.log
"GET /git/my-project.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 500 5387 "-" "git/2.30.0"
```

Apache configuration git relevant parts:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /path-to-repo
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/
Alias /git /path-to-repo
RewriteRule ^/repo-root/ - [E=AUTHREQUIRED:yes]
<Directory "/path-to-repo/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Private Git Access"
    AuthUserFile /path-to-auth-file
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/lib/git-core>
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride None
    AuthUserFile /path-to-auth-file
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

The auth file exists and is world-readable.

Questions:

1. Why doesn't it prompt for a user and pw?
2. What is the difference between requiring a valid user for the git repo directory, and the git-core directory?  Are both needed?
3. If validated by apache, will the credentials be passed to git?
4. The "Require valid-user" directives are requiring authentication for access to the apache server; but if I want to use a git credential helper, should the apache access be to allow any?

Comment: Note that this is all happening within apache, long before Git ever gets involved. Git doesn't get used until apache itself runs `git upload-pack`. There's no authorization at all on the Git end: it just runs (or doesn't if apache doesn't authenticate you first), and then obeys its input.

Answer (score 1):

To complement my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71452693/6309), the `AuthUserFile` I usually set up is in a Location directive, for `/git`, not `Directory /path-to-repo`.

See [this as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23560669/6309).

```xml
<Location /git>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Private Git Access"
  AuthUserFile "/etc/git-auth-file"
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to follow the advice on the apache page regarding "what to use when": https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html.  I thought the alias directive was just that, similar to a shell alias; I see after reading the apache description that it is not.  Thanks.

Comment: It appears that neither the RewriteRule, the <Directory /git>, nor the <Directory /usr/lib/git-core> parts are necessary. That is, it's working with only the ScriptAlias, Alias, and <Location /git> directives.  Does that make sense, or do I have something else (a security hole?) messed up?  The /git directory is outside of the normal web root.

Comment: @GaryAitken Location /git is not about a folder, but the path in the URL. (https://serverfault.com/a/196964/783)

Comment: That was a typo, I meant <Directory /path-to-repo>.  The question remains: if the git repo is outside of the normal http data hierarchy, is all that is needed the ScriptAlias, Alias, and <Location /git> directives?  That appears to be the case in my installation, but I want to make sure I'm not overlooking something.

Comment: @GaryAitken to my knowledge, yes, alias and location are enough.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my solution, arrived at thanks to help from VonC above, just so it's a little clearer for others:

In the case where the git repository is not in the normal apache web page tree, this is what is required:

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /path-to-git-repo
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/
Alias /git /path-to-git-repo
<Location "/git">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "git-developers-private"
    AuthUserFile /path-to-auth-file
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```